# Why was my post removed?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, asking-questions

I posted a question about how to rotate a tile in BufferedImage. I did it in the morning and you removed it. Why have you removed it again?

You have removed the post twice without informing/telling me the problem with the posts

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you mean this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782068/bufferedimage-help ?

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I had the urge to edit in "Tell me before I become angry -- You wouldn't like me when I'm angry"

Comment: I think you have formidable "tech rage"...

Comment: @Earlz But you know better than that by now, aye? Also, hex you Seigel! By the time I clicked "retag" it already had your fix!

Comment: @ccor yea now that I've been officially warned I can't do stuff :( *sad face*

Answer (score 12):

The only deleted post against your account is the one that starts:

> I posted a question this morning but can't find it anymore in this forum so i deceded to post it again.

If you click on your name at the top of the page, your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782068/bufferedimage-help) should be listed.

(also sending this reply via e-mail, in case it is missed)

---

Edit: a comment from Eddy on the migrated post suggests that the deleted question is in fact *not* quite the same. However, there is no other deleted question. I have undeleted the rotation question, and removed the "so I decided to post it again" comment. I'll see if I can find where that went to, but I can see no evidence of it, even with my ♦ hat on.

---

Further; I've traced 3 unregistered accounts that look like yours - 2 in active use. None of those has a question that looks *remotely* like the seemingly lost one. I can only suppose that it simply didn't get posted. I would also strongly recommend creating a *registered* account (against an OpenID) - that way it will be easier to track your old questions. If you register one of you accounts I can merge the accounts together, giving you all your old questions and answers in one place.

Comment: You're so patient with people... Just wanted to say: keep up the good work :)

Comment: Yes, yes.  This is quite the diplomatic reply.

Answer (score 2):

You reposted your question, which is not allowed. It was deleted by a moderator. Your original question is still [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782068/bufferedimage-help).